# "I care for you" versus "I care about you"

Tags: meaning, differences, prepositions, pronouns

I would like to know if there is a semantic difference between *I care for you* and *I care about you*.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Have you found [a relevant dictionary entry](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/care) and does that not answer the question? Currently, this is General Reference because that link answers the question, unless you can say why it doesn't.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I disagree. The link uses both *care for* and *care about* phrases, but not in the context the OP asks. And there are subtle differences, discussed by FumbleFingers that are not covered in the link.

Answer (score 4):

In most contexts, there's no significant difference between *for* and *about* in OP's construction. Both will be understood to mean exactly the same thing.

In some contexts - for example, *"She cared **for** her dying mother"*, it's more likely the intended sense would be that she *looked after* her mother, rather than *was emotionally attached* to her.

There are other possibilities. *"Would you care for a mink coat?"* could be asking whether you'd *like* one, ***or*** whether you'd look after it if you had one. But *"Would you care **about** a mink coat?"* would more likely be asking if you have any moral scruples about wearing bits of dead animals.

Comment: Similarly *I don't care about the elections* suggest an indifference.  *I don't care for the elections* indicates a clear dislike. And a company might say about its clients *We care about you* but would probably not say *We care for you* (unless they were a health related or other protective type organization).

Comment: @bib: Yes, there are many contexts where some possible meanings are unlikely. And as is so often the case, the likely possibilities can be dramatically affected by casting a sentence in the negative. I wouldn't care to guess how many different nuances might be conveyed by variations on OP's original.